# rearrange array data with single loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have array like :

```js
[{
  data: 3454
  id: 1
  index: 36
  name: "Pension"
}, {
  data: 53453
  id: 0
  index: 36
  name: "Pension"
}, {
  data: 6756
  id: 1
  index: 37
  name: "Pension"
}, {
  data: 453
  id: 2
  index: 37
  name: "Testval"
}, {
  data: 999
  id: 2
  index: 38
  name: "Testval"
}]
```

How can rearrange this array with single loop as below ?
I need to rearrange data like :

```js
'Pension': {
  0: {
    36: 53453
  }
  1: {
    36: 3454,
    37: 6756
  }
},
'Testval': {
  2: {
    37: 453
  }
},
```

I tried with loops but it have 6-7 loops. and I need to do with less loop.

Comment: Homework? Assignment?

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why down vote ?

Comment: @AnkitSoni You need to specify two things **1)** logic of rearrangement **2)** your attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a single loop with default values for not given objects. Later assign the value.

```js
var array = [{ data: 3454, id: 1, index: 36, name: "Pension" }, { data: 53453, id: 0, index: 36, name: "Pension" }, { data: 6756, id: 1, index: 37, name: "Pension" }, { data: 453, id: 2, index: 37, name: "Testval" }, { data: 999, id: 2, index: 38, name: "Testval" }],
    result = {};

array.forEach(function (o) {
    result[o.name] = result[o.name] || {};
    result[o.name][o.id] = result[o.name][o.id] || {};
    result[o.name][o.id][o.index] = o.data;
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With a more dynamic approach for arbitrary nested objects.

```js
var array = [{ data: 3454, id: 1, index: 36, name: "Pension" }, { data: 53453, id: 0, index: 36, name: "Pension" }, { data: 6756, id: 1, index: 37, name: "Pension" }, { data: 453, id: 2, index: 37, name: "Testval" }, { data: 999, id: 2, index: 38, name: "Testval" }],
    result = {};

array.forEach(function (o) {
    [o.name, o.id].reduce(function (r, k) {
        return r[k] = r[k] || {};
    }, result)[o.index] = o.data;
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks @nina , I want to do  same thing. You save my day :)

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using single loop of array in java as below:

1. create a class with fields index and data
2. create a Map as Map as Map
3. iterate an array and store the value in the map.

I guess this is the effective way. try it.